# Why am I getting core dumped?

Tags: c, pointers

Please help me. I can't figure out why I get a core dumped when I run this program. Before returning anything I can print `all_albums_p` just fine. Why am I getting `core dumped`?

```
#include "music_server.h"

struct album_ {
  int num_tracks;
  char **tracks;
  int **playlist_hits;

};
typedef struct album_ album;

album *parse_album(FILE *album_file,int *number_of_albums){

  int number_of_album,number_of_tracks,number_of_charaters;
  int i,j;
  char dummy_space;
  int *p;

  fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_album);

  *number_of_albums = number_of_album;

  album *all_albums_p = (album *)malloc(sizeof(album)*number_of_album);

  for(j=0;j<number_of_album;j++){

    fscanf(album_file,"%d", &all_albums_p[j].num_tracks);

    all_albums_p[j].tracks = calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(char));
    all_albums_p[j].playlist_hits = calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(int));

    /*Line 27*/ for(i=0;i<all_albums_p[j].num_tracks;i++){

      fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_charaters);

      all_albums_p[j].tracks[i] = (char *)calloc(number_of_charaters+1,sizeof(char));
      all_albums_p[j].playlist_hits[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
      all_albums_p[j].playlist_hits[i] = 0;
      fscanf(album_file," ",dummy_space);
      fscanf(album_file, "%[^\n]s", all_albums_p[j].tracks[i]);
    }
  }
  return all_albums_p;
}

main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int i,j;
  int *number_of_albums,*number_of_tracks,a;
  a=0;
  number_of_albums = &a;

  album *all_tracks_ptr;

  album_file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  transaction_file = fopen(argv[2],"r");

  if((album_file == NULL) || (transaction_file == NULL)){
    printf("Either %s or %s could not be open");
  }else{

    all_tracks_ptr = parse_album(album_file,number_of_albums);


    int number_of_tracks[*number_of_albums];
  }
}
```

errors:

`Bus Error (core dumped)`

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xff277c9c in _smalloc () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xff277d10 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xff263830 in calloc () from /lib/libc.so.1
#3  0x00010dd8 in parse_album (album_file=0xff3675bc,
    number_of_albums=0xffbff894) at functions.c:27
#4  0x00010b80 in main (argc=3, argv=0xffbff90c) at project3.c:19
```

Comment: Is is just me that don't see your number_of_albums declaration in main()?

Comment: I also don't see the open of album_file.  I assume you omitted it for brevity, but if you're hunting for bugs, you need to include more, not less.

Comment: I didn't copy all my code. Just edit it with all my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should  allocate `sizeof(char*)` below instead of `sizeof(char)`

```
all_albums_p[j].tracks = alloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed a lot of my problems. But why?

Comment: The size of a char is nearly always 8 bits. A pointer to a char (an address) is up to 64 bits on modern systems.

Answer (score 1):

Since that looks like a Unix message ("Bus Error (core dumped)) I will assume you are using some flavor of Unix.

So, compile your program with debugging info output turned on and with optimization turned off.  If you're using `gcc` or something gcc-compatible, that would be the `-g -O0` command line options.

Then run your program and have it crash.  Locate the core dump (I'll call it `corefile` in this example) and then type:

```
gdb programname corefile
```

Then when you get the gdb prompt, type `bt` (for `backtrace`) to see the program's stackframe.  That will tell you where the program crashed and you can examine that part of your program more closely.

---

**Update:**

I think your problem is here:

```
all_albums_p[j].tracks = calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(char));
```

`album.tracks` is defined as `char**`.  However, what you're assigning to `all_albums_p[j].tracks` is a block of memory the size of `num_tracks` `char`.  You  need to assign to it a block of memory big enough to hold `num_tracks` `char *`.  So you probably need to change the line to:

```
all_albums_p[j].tracks = (char **) calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(char *));
```

Comment: How do I name corefile. I did this >>`gcc -o project3 project3.c functions.c -g -O0`

Comment: The default name is often simply `core`.  Though your system may be configred to use a different default name.  See `man core` and look for a section like "Naming of core dump files".  In any event, it should be dumped to the directory you were in when you ran the program (assuming your program doesn't internally change the current working directory which I'd very much doubt yours does).

Comment: edited question with the bt thing. Can you help me take a look at it? I have no idea what the numbers are.

Comment: What line in the code you show is line 27 of functions.c?  And definitely do try running `valgrind` as others suggest.

Comment: In line 27 is `for(i=0;i<all_albums_p[j].num_tracks;i++){`.I don't know if we have valgrid my professor didn't teach us that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger or valgrind and figure out what line the problem is occurring on.  Then you will know what part of your code is bad.

Comment: Not necessarily. Crashes can occur at very different places than their root cause.

Comment: I think it is `all_tracks_ptr = parse_album(album_file,number_of_albums);` that is causing the problem.

Comment: @KendallFrey: True.  Often valgrind is helpful in such cases when gdb is not.

Comment: @LearningC: Um, commenting out that line makes your program do absolutely nothing.  So of course that fixes it.  Try using valgrind and report back.